# Rails 4: How to load css.scss files from amazon s3

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3

I have uploaded all my assets (images, css, js) to amazon s3. I am able to load images and js files successfully in my production environment. But css files are not loading. My css files are having extension as css.scss (ex. application.css.scss). I tried changing the extension from css.scss to css then also it is not loading but the error saying "unable to load application.css" is gone. Can anyone help me with this issue?